# problema en establecer conexión con Arduino y bluetooth hc05

Tags: arduino

Buenas amigos lo que pasa que este tengo problema al establecer la conexión mediante arduino y bluetooth. Este mi código (primero bien me funciono con este codigo ahora no se cual sera problema)

```
 int key;   
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()){
 int key=Serial.read();
}
if (key == 'A') {
digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
}
else if(key == 'a')
{
digitalWrite(8, LOW);
}
if (key == 'B') {
digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
}
else if(key == 'b')
{
digitalWrite(9, LOW);
}
if (key == 'C') {
digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
}
else if(key == 'c')
{
digitalWrite(10, LOW);
}
if (key == 'D') {
digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
}
else if(key == 'd')
{
digitalWrite(11, LOW);
}
}
```

Comment: Yo use estas explicaciones cuando me toco trabajar con arduino. https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Setting_up_Bluetooth_HC-05_with_Arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He modificado tu código, pruebo esto:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available()){
    char key = Serial.read();

    if (key == 'A'){
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    }
    else if(key == 'a'){
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    }
    if (key == 'B'){
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    }
    else if(key == 'b'){
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    }
    if (key == 'C'){
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    }
    else if(key == 'c'){
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    }
    if (key == 'D'){
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    }
    else if(key == 'd'){
      digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: gracias ante mano. me fue de mucha ayuda!!

Comment: @alexanderBajañaOrtiz No hay de qué.